# full text search in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, search, full-text-search, sql-like

I have a query to search keywords using like, but I also want to search full text so I changed it to full text search query, but it doesn't work.

The old query that's working fine:

```
$data = $this->db
    ->select('content.title,content.id,content.category,content.body,path')
    ->from('content')   
    ->join('categories','content.category = categories.id')             
    ->like('content.title', $searchterm)
    ->like('content.body', $searchterm)
    ->order_by("content.id","DESC")
    ->get();
```

and this is my new query for full text search:

```
$data = $this->db
    ->select('content.title,content.id,content.category,content.body,path')
    ->from('content')   
    ->join('categories','content.category = categories.id')                 
    ->where('MATCH (content.body, content.title) AGAINST ("'. $searchterm .'")')
    ->order_by("content.id","DESC")
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. if you are using mysql version 5.5 or lower, make sure all the tables involved have the engine *MyISAM*.
2. make sure the your column has the *FULLTEXT INDEX*.
3. where() takes 3 arguments, example:

   ```
   $this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
   $this->db->get('table');
   ```
4. more than one columns in `match()` triggers Error Number: 1191, so separate them:

   ```
   ->where('MATCH (content.title) AGAINST ("'. $searchterm .'")')
   ->where('MATCH (content.body) AGAINST ("'. $searchterm .'")')
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try by changing the `where` clause in your query, see if it helps:

```
->where('MATCH (content.body, content.title) AGAINST ("'. $searchterm .'")', NULL, false)
```

This sets the value to `NULL` and tells CI not to escape the string.

Answer (score 0):

you did not use the correct syntax of mathch .... against
try this:

```
    ->where MATCH (content.body, content.title) AGAINST ("'. $searchterm .'") > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple column you can use them in single line like this:

```
->where("MATCH(title, model) AGAINST('$text')", null, false);
```

or just one column:

```
->where("MATCH(title) AGAINST('$text')", null, false);
```

don't forget to escape your inputs. because we disabled escaping with that false over there. use this for escaping:

```
$text = $this->db->escape_str($text);
```